# msg.exe windows 7 LAN fail

Tags: windows

If i only do
  msg * hi
it only prompts me of the message. Same as the following:
  msg * /server:KLJ-PC hi
  msg * /server:192.168.2.2

However i got another computer on the LAN, called JO-PC (probably 192.168.2.3) but whatever i do to try send a message to that laptop it won't work. I get a error like:
  1825 getting session names

I assume external access for messaging is disabled as anyone on internet could message u. But on a home LAN shouldnt it be enabled at default (easily detect its a LAN) and if not how do i enable it?

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely failing because the messenger service doesn't exist as a service in Windows 7.

On a side note, the messenger service has come disabled out of the box for a long time now and should be disabled in other OSes.